# Python: Build edges based on nested list

Tags: python, nested, networkx

I need an example to build edges based on nested list in python.

Current code:

```
data = [257, [269, [325]],[4,''],[0,'']]

def iter(o, tree_types=(list, tuple)):
    if isinstance(o, tree_types):
            
        for value in o:
                    
           if isinstance(value, list):

               for subvalue in iter(value, list):
                   yield subvalue
           else:
               yield value
    else:
       yield o

final_list = list(iter(data)) 
print('\nfinal_list = {0}'.format(final_list))

edges = []

l = final_list

for first, second in zip(l, l[1:]):
    edges.append((first, second))

print('\nedges:{0}'.format(edges))
```

Current Output:
final_list = [257, 269, 325, 4, '', 0, '']
edges = [(257, 269), (269, 325), (325, 4), (4, ''), ('', 0), (0, '')]

Desired output:

```
edges = [(257, 269), (269, 325), (257, 4), (4, ''), (257,0), (0, '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is you have flattened the list (of lists) and therefore no longer know which nodes where joined to which. The use of `zip` assumes these have been lined up in pairs somehow.

If your iterator yields a source and destination or sink node in a pair, you can preserve this.

You aren't using the `tree_types`, so without that, this works for your input:

```
def iter(o):
    source = o[0]
    for subgraph in o[1:]:
        if isinstance(subgraph, list):
            yield from iter(subgraph)
            sink = subgraph[0]
            if isinstance(sink, list):
                yield (source, sink[0])
            else:
                yield (source, sink)
        else:
            yield (source, subgraph)
```

This has a few assumptions... for example, that the data isn't empty and the first item is a single node.